# Map data in React to array of objects

Tags: reactjs

When using  react-select it demands an array of objects, not of data.
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/5032
"react-select does not actively support options that are just simple strings."

I have a list of cities, and I need to change that list to an object

```
[{ label: "city", value: "city" }].
    const [selectData, setSelectData] = useState([{ label: "city", value: "city" }]);
```

function This iterates over the data and should create an object array. But it doesn't....

```
const CreateSelectData = () => {
var getSelectDataList = [];
allCities.map(
  (city, index) =>
    (getSelectDataList = [...selectData,{label:city, value: city])
);
setSelectData(getSelectDataList);
};
```

output

```
 <Select
        options={selectData}
        className='optioncity'
        value='Select a city'
        onChange={handleCityChange}
      />
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong, but I have looked at it for hours :-)
The Select never loads at all

Comment: Assuming `allCities` is coming from an API call, please try this as soon as the array is available: `setSelectData(allCities.map(city => ({label: city, value: city})));`.

Comment: _The Select never loads at all_ - at what point in the control-flow is `CreateSelectData` method being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is to transform from the original object into another object, but for your case, you should use `forEach` instead. And  you should expand `getSelectDataList` which is your new array instead of `selectData`

```
const CreateSelectData = () => {
var getSelectDataList = [...selectData]; //initialise with your initial `selectData`
allCities.forEach((city, index) => {
   getSelectDataList = getSelectDataList.push({ id: index, name: city })
});
setSelectData(getSelectDataList);
};
```

If you want to use `map`. You can try this way

```
const CreateSelectData = () => {
   var getSelectDataList = allCities.map((city, index) => ({ id: index, name: city })); //create a new list with your expected value
   setSelectData([...selectData, ...getSelectDataList]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function change

```
allCities.map((city) =>
    (getSelectDataList = [...selectData, { label: city, value: city }])
);
```

to

```
allCities.map((city) =>
    (getSelectDataList = [...getSelectDataList, { label: city, value: city }])
);
```

Comment: a better option might be to use a reduce statement than a map. what you are doing should work but its better to use a reduce.